# Capturing and caching headers for each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

We are limiting access to an enterprise system by forcing the client to make their CRUD calls through our application, and then our application will forward that very same request to its destination, saving the header information.

1. Client makes a request to an `ApiController`
2. We pass the request to the service layer
3. The service layer forwards the request its intended enterprise system destination.

To elaborate on the points above:

The client issues a request against this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("opportunities({id:guid})")]
    [Route("opportunities")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity()
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() + Request.RequestUri.Query;
        var response = await _opportunityService.GetOpportunity(query);
        return response;
    }
```

The service method GetOpportunity is defined as:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity(string query)
    {//at the line below is where i want to send the same headers that were passed in originally at step 1
        var response = Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query); //this is just using HttpClient to make this call
        var responseType = response.Result.StatusCode;
        if (responseType == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = responseType
            };
        return await response;
    }
```

**How do we save the header information from Step 1?**

By using the following middleware I have been able to grab ALL header information; however, I am not sure on how to *cache* them or make them available to the service layer:

```
public class HeaderAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically acting as a proxy. I see a few possible options.

One would be to pass the Original Request into the service as an explicit dependency

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("opportunities({id:guid})")]
[Route("opportunities")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity() {
    var response = await _opportunityService.GetOpportunity(this.Request);
    return response;
}
```

and extract the information there

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOpportunity(HttpRequestMessage Request) {
    //at the line below is where i want to send the same headers that were passed in originally at step 1
    var query = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() + Request.RequestUri.Query;
    var headers = Request.Headers;
    var url = Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query;
    //create new request and copy headers
    var proxy = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    foreach (var header in headers) {
        proxy.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }
    var response = await Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy);//This is an assumption.
    var responseType = response.StatusCode; //Do not mix blocking calls. It can deadlock
    if (responseType == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        return new HttpResponseMessage {
            StatusCode = responseType
        };
    return response;
}
```

If you do not want to mix the layers and concerns you can extract the needed information into your own model and pass that to the service in order to recreate the needed request.

Comment: coool!! in this case, we can just merge the two layers

Comment: They will be both dealing with HttpRequestMessages and HttpResponseMessages so I don't see why not. It simplifies the controller given that it is just a pass through service.

Comment: There is room for improvement but I believe this is a start.

Comment: im wondering if a more functional approach would be in order here, something like a Reader monad https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/category-theory-via-c-sharp-20-more-monad-reader-monad

Comment: Wow. I would need more time to look that over to get a better understanding of what it does and how it ties into your problem.

Comment: yes i would highly suggest looking at functional programming in general, it will make anyone a much better programmer, this guy is my favorite http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/20/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/  he's get the best pluralsight courses

Comment: when you said "var response = await Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy);//This is an assumption." --- what do you mean by this is an assumption>?

Comment: also can you elaborate on this comment regarding deadlocking... var responseType = response.StatusCode; //Do not mix blocking calls. It can deadlock

Comment: I do not know what your code looks like so I was assuming you had a `SendAsync` method that took `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: As for the deadlock if you have an async/await method and then call `.Result` on a task you will end up with a deadlock, breaking your code.